# Sharepoint Web template

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have created a web template solution by following Vesa "vesku" Juvonen 's blog(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx).

I have the web template and have created sub sites with it. Now I need to create a web template from this template, which would consist of lists and other items. 
The publishing feature does not have the save as template option, So I get into the _layouts/savetmpl.aspx to create one or deactivate the publishing feature to create getthe "save as site template option and create one. It creates but does not work properly.
 I access the site by appending the default.aspx to the newly created sites url and it does not have any features as that of root template. Is there any way to create a template from the existing web template to work correctly. I am a newbie to sharepoint and vesku's blog has been my reference.
Any options or views to do it correctly would be helpful.

---

I have thought about creating a site through code and given the user an option to do so by including a web part where he could click on say "create a webs site with XXX template and include XXX lists, web parts etc. Is it a good approach?

Comment: SharePoint related questions would be very welcome on [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) - you might want to consider posting it there, or better still asking for it to be migrated.

Answer (score 1):

If the web site that you created a template for contains web parts that access the GAC (i.e. have DLL's), then you must take the wsp that is in the solution gallery and deploy it as a farm solution.

Templates saved via /_layouts/savetmpl.aspx cannot access the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

if you made a webtemplate why would you want to use the save as site template option? Users can also create sites from your webtemplate and if you need a different template you just add another webtemplate.

The whole principal of web templates is meant to be used for site creation....